# Device changes to unknown after running app in android studio

Tags: android-studio

When i connect my galaxy s8 to computer android studio recognizes it, and i can run my app. But after runnig it changes to unknown device, and i have to restart android studio to make it recognize phone again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

rarely happens with me, I use following commands

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

if you can't find adb, it is in the platform tools folder in android sdk directory, mine is at `/home/arch/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/`

You need to change directory to that folder and run the commands.

You can search for where android sdk is located for your platform

edit:
if that doesn't solve the problem, then you can use adb wireless method, you can search for it (This solved the problem of OP)

Comment: unfortunately didnt work, after starting server and using ADB devices it doesnt show any device, and if i unplug and plug it again it shows device is offline.

Comment: the version of SDK tools is 26.1.1

Comment: and what about android sdk platform tools?

Comment: sdk platform tools is 29.0.2

Comment: you are using wired connection or wireless?

Comment: im using  usb cable , tried my second cable and got same issue

Comment: can you give a try to wireless method?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot

Comment: you don't need to have wifi router you can do it by using your phone hotspot too

Comment: i have a wifi router, my computer finds the phone but doesnt want to connct to it.

Comment: ok i did te process of connecting it via wi-fi using this toutorial http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-connect and it solved my problem. thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have some other process or server running on one of the ports that Android Studio uses to communicate with emulators. These are typically ports 5555, 5556, 5557, etc.

There are a couple of OS-specific ways to check if something is running on those ports. On macOS for example you can run:

```
lsof -nP -i4TCP:5555,5556,5557 | grep LISTEN
```

The first column in the results will tell you what process is listening on that port.